# Unit testing a compiler

Tags: unit-testing, parsing, tdd, compiler-theory, abstract-syntax-tree

What is considered the best approach to unit test a complex unit such as a compiler?

I've written a few compilers and interpreters over the years, and I do find this kind of code quite hard to test in a good way.

If we take something like the Abstract Syntax Tree generation. how would you test this using TDD?

Small constructs might be easy to test.
e.g. something along the lines of:

```
string code = @"public class Foo {}";
AST ast = compiler.Parse(code);
```

Since that won't generate alot of ast nodes.

But if I actually want to test that the compiler can generate an AST for something like a method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_parse_integer_instance_method_in_class ()
{
   string code = @"public class Foo {  public int method(){ return 0;}}";
   AST ast = compiler.Parse(code);
```

What would you assert on?
Manually defining an AST that represents the given code and make an assertion that the generated AST conforms to the manually defined AST seems horribly combersome and might even be error prone.

So what are the best tactics for TDD'ing complex scenarios like this?

Comment: It's just one of the numerous examples of why unit tests are useless and inferior, and the focus should be on an integration testing. TDD is for CRUD, not for the serious stuff. For compilers, random generated code testing is by far the best possible approach. E.g.: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/pldi11-preprint.pdf

Comment: You may also be interested in a superior approach to safe compiler construction: http://compcert.inria.fr/doc/index.html - formal specification is definitely a better guarantee of quality than any possible testing.

Comment: @peer, what "methods" are you talking about? If a parser is generated (think `bison` and alike), you'll have a monolithic grammar and unreadable pile of a generated code. Nothing to test besides the grammar as a whole. If it's a handwritten recursive descent parser, it's even harder to unit-test (see, say, Clang source code and try to think of how to mock the ASTContext and an input stream for each tiny parser entry). Unit testing is truly pointless for any reasonably complicated code.

Comment: @SK-logic I'm all with you on this one, I have always found this sort of code near impossible to develop using TDD, So the post is made to see if the TDD experts know something that I don't in this context. or if it simply is like you say, TDD is for CRUD.

Comment: I have no experience with writing compilers whatsoever, so this is a first-glance-answer and sorry if I'm talking out of my ass: I see no real difference with unit testing a service consumer for instance, and that's done best by stubbing the service results. You could use real service (or in this case, parser) output as assertion data for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all parsing is usually a trivial part of compiler project. From my experience it never takes more than 10% of the time (unless we are talking about C++ but you wouldn't be asking questions here if you were designing it) so you'd rather not invest much of your time into parser tests.

Still, TDD (or however you call it) has it's share in developing the middle-end where you often want to verify that e.g. optimizations that you've just added actually did result in expected code transformation. From my experience, tests like this are usually implemented by giving compiler specially crafted test programs and grepping output assembly for expected patterns (was this loop unrolled four times? did we manage to avoid memory writes is this function? etc.). Grepping assembly isn't as good as analyzing structured representation (S-exprs or XML) but it's cheap and works fine in most cases. It's awfully hard to support as your compiler grows though.

Comment: I've actually used s-expressions in testing before. eg. making my AST able to ToString() itself into an s-expression.. and then simply assert that the result is equal to the expected s-expression.. works nice, however it feels hack'ish. or?

Comment: Well, it is hackish but usually people choose to live with that and not invest too much time into tests (noone loves testing really). It may help to only grep for subexpression and/or allow some tolerance (different registers or label names).

Comment: BTW here is a nice example : [LLVM's lit infrastructure](http://llvm.org/docs/TestingGuide.html)

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, if you test a compiler, you cannot get enough tests!  Users really rely on compiler-generated output as if it were an always-golden-standard, so really be aware of quality.  So if you can, test with every test you can come up with!

Secondly, use all testing methods available, yet use them where appropriate. Indeed, you may be able to mathematically prove, that a certain transformation is correct. If you are able to do so, you should.

But every compiler that I've seen some internals of involves heuristics and a lot of optimized, hand-crafted code at its internals; thus assisted proving methods typically are not applicable any more.  Here, testing comes in place, and I mean a lot of it!

When collecting tests, please consider different cases:

1. Positive Standard-Conformance: your frontend should accept certain code patterns and the compiler must produce a correctly running program thereof.  Tests in this category either need a golden-reference compiler or generator that produces the correct output of the test-program; or it involves hand-written programs that include a check against values furnished by human reasoning.
2. Negative Tests: every compiler has to reject faulty code, like syntax errors, type mismatches et cetera. It must produce certain types of error and warning messages.  I don't know of any method to auto-generate such tests.  So these need to be human-written, too.
3. Transformation tests:  whenever you come up with a fancy optimization within your compiler (middle-end), you probably have some example code in mind that demonstrates the optimization. Be aware of transformations before and after such a module, they might need special options to your compiler or a bare-bone compiler with just that module plugged-in.  Test a reasonable big set of surrounding module combinations, too.  I usually did regression-testing on the intermediate representation before and after the specific transformation, defining a reference by intensive reasoning with colleagues.  Try to write code on both sides of the transformation, i.e. code snippets that you want to have transformed and slightly different ones that must not be.

Now, this sounds like an awful lot of work!  Yes it does, but there is help:  there are several, commercial test-suites for (C-) compilers out in the world and experts that might help you in applying them. Here a small list of those known to me:

- [ACE: SuperTest Compiler Test and Validation Suite](http://www.ace.nl/compiler/supertest-compiler-test-and-validation-suite)
- Perennial C Compiler Validation Suite
- [Bugseng: ECLAIR](http://bugseng.com/products/eclair)
- Tests in the GCC and LLVM environment
- you name it! Or google "Compiler Test Suite"

Comment: This is the noble high level integration testing, not that weird "unit-testing" stuff so much loved by the hordes of the web-coding hipsters.